# How can I pipe a filename to tar?

Tags: bash

I think this command should work but it doesn't. I am trying to pipe the highest filename numbered file to `tar`

```
ls file-* | tail -1 | tar -xvf
```

It tells me that the -f option requires an argument so I figured I needed to redirect stdin to tar but this doesn't work either...

```
tar -xvf < ls file-* | tail -1
```

I know I can store it in a variable probably but I would like to do it in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your filename don't contain any whitespace/glob characters you can do this:

```
ls file-* | tail -1 | xargs tar -xvf
```

Answer (score 3):

If your filenames are containing whitespaces or globs, you can do this:

```
tar -xvf "$(ls file-* | tail -1)"
```

This is called a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution), and its result will be properly quoted if it is surrounded by double quotes. So, for example, if the filenames are

```
file-01
file-02
```

the command will be expanded to

```
tar -xvf "file-02"
```

And this will work even with whitespaces and globs, because they are quoted.